# MySQL default value based on view

Tags: mysql, view

Basically I have a bunch of views based on a simple discriminator column (eg. CREATE VIEW tablename AS SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE discrcolumn = "discriminator value").

Upon inserting a new row into this view, it should insert "discriminator value" into `discrcolumn`.

I tried this, but apparently MySQL doesn't figure this out itself, as it throws an error "Field of view viewname underlying table does not have a default value". The discriminator column is set to NOT NULL of course.

How do I mend this? Perhaps a pre-insert trigger?

UPDATE: Triggers won't work on views, see below comment.

Would it work to create a trigger on the table which uses a variable, and set that variable at establishing the connection? For each connection the value of that variable would be the same, but it could differ from other connections.

EDIT:

This appears to work...

Setup:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_[tablename] BEFORE INSERT ON [tablename] 
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.[discrcolumn] = @variable
```

Runtime:

```
SET @variable = [descrvalue];
INSERT INTO [viewname] ([columnlist]) VALUES ([values]);
```

Comment: I tried a trigger, but it doesn't work.

`'CREATE TRIGGER insert_account_[discrval] BEFORE INSERT ON [viewname] FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.[discrname] = '[discrval]''`

General error: 1347 '[viewname]' is not BASE TABLE'

It says so in the docs as well: "You cannot associate a trigger with a TEMPORARY table or a view.": http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need anything quite so complicated as that. If you created a view such as

```
CREATE VIEW MYVIEW AS 
    SELECT COLUMN1,
           COLUMN2,
           DISCRIMINATOR_COLUMN
        FROM MYTABLE
        WHERE DISCRIMINATOR_COLUMN = 1;
```

you could then insert into this view thus...

```
INSERT INTO MYVIEW (COLUMN1,
                    COLUMN2,
                    DISCRIMINATOR_COLUMN)
    VALUES (1, 2, 3)
```

and the view should update correctly if all the columns in the table that aren't present in the view have suitable defaults. Note that the new value in `DISCRIMINATOR_COLUMN` needn't be the value picked out in the view, although naturally it won't appear in the view when next selected unless it is.

Comment: Yes, you can manually insert the discirminator value, but the whole point is not to. The point is having fooling the application into thinking it operates on a dedicated database, when in reality it shares the database with other instances of the application. Perhaps I should have communicated this goal more clearly.

Comment: @Jake, perhaps I should study the question more carefully. May I suggest that you don't then select the discriminator column in your view, to prevent this sort of thing from happening inadvertently?