# Default values when inserting into a view

Tags: mysql, view

I have the following view [canadian_users]:

```
SELECT id, name, email
FROM users
WHERE country_id = 3;
```

It works just fine for selecting data. What I want to know is, how can I make data I insert *into* the view default to `country_id = 3`?

For example, when I insert into the view now, the `country_id` is `NULL`

```
INSERT INTO canadian_users (name, email) VALUES ("bob", "foo@bar.com");
=> 
  name: bob
  email: foo@bar.com
  country_id: NULL
```

Is there a way I can make it such that `country_id` would **default** to `3`?

```
INSERT INTO canadian_users (name, email) VALUES ("bob", "foo@bar.com");
=> 
  name: bob
  email: foo@bar.com
  country_id: 3
```

I do **not** want to set the column's default value to 3 on the `users` table. There will be similar views to this.

Also, my entire situation is truncated to make for a neat SO question. Yes, the view is necessary, and it's not likely that I'll be able to actually set `country_id` in my `INSERT` statement.

Comment: I also just found another question like this on SO at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836759/mysql-default-value-based-on-view?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible. The only alternative I can think of is calling a stored procedure/function instead of an `INSERT` statement. Something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_canadian_user( name VARCHAR(20), email VARCHAR(20) )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users
    VALUE (name, email, country_id);
END
```

However, I find it hard to believe you cannot add the `country_id` to your `INSERT` statement. I imagine your application has a routine that essentially selects the view to access, presumably based on the country of your user (eg. when the user logs in). Then you could store the corresponding `country_id` along.